# Least squares regression with two predictor variables (exponential functions of time)

Tags: statistics, physics, least-squares

[Question cropped from textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWVRL.png)
(Apologies for the link- I don't have enough rep to post the actual image.) [Now pasted below. Ed.]

[image]

I've come across a question in a textbook (linked above) requiring a least-squares fitted model of a sum of exponential terms. I have some experience using the least-squares criterion with single terms, ie  fitting a curve $y = Ae^x$ to some data, but none with sums of terms. Would it suffice to fit separate curves to each term?

I'm not at all confident in my approach here, thanks for any help.

Comment: Your model is actually linear, since the parameters are $C_A$ and $C_B$, and nothing inside the exponential. That is, you can replace $t$ by the values it takes, compute the exponential, end what you get is your actual regressor.

Comment: What do you mean by "regressor"? How does plugging in values of $t$ give me the parameters? My professor told us explicitly to estimate the values of $C_A$ and $C_B$ by fitting a least-squares model of the form given in the question. I don't see how to do that, given that he has only ever had us fit models with one term, not multiple terms in a sum.

Comment: Regressor = independent variable (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) for other commonly used vocabulary). What is it, here? Hint: it's what's behind the parameters.

Comment: Thanks a ton, youre a great help. Here, the regressor is time, correct? Why am I looking for $t$? The values for $t$ are given in the table- or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: Now, there are two regressors, given by $exp(-0.03t_i)$ and $exp(-0.05t_i)$ respectively. Call them $X_1$ and $X_2$ if you prefer, and your model is $y=C_AX_1+C_BX_2+\varepsilon$. These exponentials serve no purpose in the regression, they just have you mistakenly think you are facing a nonlinear regression, which is *not* the case. It would be different if there were an unknown parameter inside the exponential, say you don't know the disintegration constants and you write $y=C_Aexp(-k_A t)+C_Bexp(-k_B t)+\varepsilon$, with unknown $k_A$ and $k_B$. But here, no such thing.

Comment: All we seem to have done is replace the exponential terms with $X_1$ and $X_2$. I don't see how that gets us any closer to an answer. Sorry, I don't see where you're going with that.

Comment: Maybe I should have start with this: What do you know about multilinear regression?

Comment: Let's say we use $X_1$ and $X_2$ instead of the exponential terms, then- where would I go after that? I feel like if I knew where the next step was going I could connect it to the terms and methods we have used in class.

Comment: Everything is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), from the description of the model, to the computation of parameters. Read on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have received excellent advice in the Comments and an earlier Answer. Maybe it will help you to understand what they are suggesting and doing, if you see this done in a more familiar format.

I have chosen to use Minitab software because it has
clearly labeled output. To start I put amount (y) and time (t)
from the data table (in your link) into two columns of the
Minitab worksheet. At the beginning of the Minitab session, I
print these out for reference.

```
 MTB > print c1 c2

 Data Display 

 Row    y  t
   1  8.8  5
   2  8.6  6
   3  8.2  7
   4  7.9  8

 MTB > name c3 'x1' c4 'x2'
 MTB > let  'x1' = exp(-.03*'t')
 MTB > let  'x2' = exp(-.05*'t')
 MTB > print c1-c4

 Data Display 

 Row    y  t        x1        x2
   1  8.8  5  0.860708  0.778801
   2  8.6  6  0.835270  0.740818
   3  8.2  7  0.810584  0.704688
   4  7.9  8  0.786628  0.670320
```

Then I do linear regression
of y on two columns x1 and x2 defined as suggested in the helpful
Comment by @Jeam-ClaudeArbaut. I do regression without a 
constant term ('forced through the origin') because your model
has no constant term.

```
 MTB > Regress 'y' 2 'x1' 'x2';
 SUBC>   NoConstant;            # force through origin
 SUBC>   Brief 2.               # amount of detail in printout
```

Minitab results agree with those in the excellent Answer by @LorenLugosch. (+1)
[If there is a lot of regression your future, please make it
your goal to understand that approach.]

```
 Regression Analysis: y versus x1, x2 

 The regression equation is
 y = 6.66 x1 + 4.00 x2          # more accurate coef's in table


 Predictor    Coef  SE Coef     T      P
 Noconstant
 x1          6.657    1.763  3.78  0.063
 x2          3.999    2.003  2.00  0.184

 S = 0.0647461                 # Square of this is MS(Resid Err)

 Analysis of Variance

 Source          DF      SS      MS         F      P
 Regression       2  281.04  140.52  33520.73  0.000
 Residual Error   2    0.01    0.00
 Total            4  281.05


 Source  DF  Seq SS
 x1       1  281.02
 x2       1    0.02
```

Answer (score 1):

If we call the data which we measured $z$, we can model $z$ as $y + w$, where $w$ is some noise. We can rewrite $y = Ue^{-0.03t} + Ve^{-0.05t}$ as $y = H\theta$, where $H$ is
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        e^{-0.03*5} & e^{-0.05*5}\\
        e^{-0.03*6} & e^{-0.05*6}\\
        e^{-0.03*7} & e^{-0.05*7}\\
        e^{-0.03*8} & e^{-0.05*8}\\
        \end{matrix}
$$
and $\theta = [\begin{matrix}
       U & V \end{matrix}]$. The best estimate of $\theta$ is $(H^TH)^{-1}H^Tz$. ($(H^TH)^{-1}H^T$ is called the pseudo-inverse of $H$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse). If we do the linear algebra, we get that the estimate of $[\begin{matrix}
       U & V \end{matrix}]$ is equal to [6.6571 3.9994].

(There might be a less complicated way to do this, but this is just the mechanical way I learned recently.)

Comment: I have to find the parameters by use of a least-squares model.

Comment: This really is a least-squares model- it just looks a little weird.

Comment: But Jean-Claude Arbaut is right: this problem looks nonlinear, but really the exponential terms are basically like constants.

Comment: I can't in good conscience use methods I don't understand, and that don't resemble methods I've learned. Thanks though, your values will be helpful to check mine against when I get them,